# Uncaught (in promise) when calling multiple ajax within router model

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I calling multiple API endpoint within ember router model
I'm using ember-cli 3.11.0
When I refresh the page, it failed to load with "Uncaught (in promise)" which point specifically in $.ajax call

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import { hash } from 'rsvp';

export default Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function (param) {
    return hash({
      category: $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/catalog/category/' + param.id,
        type: 'GET'
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res;
      }),
      categories: $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/catalog/category',
        type: 'GET'
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res;
      })
    })
  }
});
```

With those codes, I want to call inside setupController something like

```
setupController(ctrl, model) {
   console.log(model.category);
   console.log(model.categories);
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using [`ember-ajax`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax), which is part of Ember's default blueprint?  Isn't there any information about the error that wasn't catched? If so, you should catch and log the error to gather additional information. What is the result of the network requests? If it's not returning a `200` or isn't valid json but including a `Content-Type: application/json` header `jQuery.ajax()` will throw. I would recommend using [`fetch`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch) instead of `jQuery.ajax()` for new applications.

Comment: It because I'm using legacy code that has utils calling jQuery.ajax(),
I guess I had to refactor those ajax() and replace it with fetch
Anyway turnout the error that I'm having because within model, param attribute doesn't match with declared param name in router, stupid me :D
Thanks you for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola @ave  thanks for your question!

As @jelhan mentions in their comment to you, it is recommended that you use `fetch` now as it is a much more modern API than using `$.ajax()` from jQuery.

If you need to support older browsers like IE11 I would recommend installing ember-fetch by following the README instructions on https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch which is essentially just the following:

```sh
ember install ember-fetch
```

Then you can update your example to be the following:

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import fetch from 'fetch';
import { hash } from 'rsvp';

export default Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model(param) {
    return hash({
      category: fetch('http://localhost:8000/catalog/category/' + param.id)
        .then((res) => res.json()),
      categories: fetch('http://localhost:8000/catalog/category')
        .then((res) => res.json()),
    })
  }
});
```

Now for your actual error, I would imagine that the error that you are seeing with "Uncaught (in promise)" is that actually one of these requests is failing for some reason  I would recommend adding an error page following the [Error Substate documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_error-substates) and for the template include the following

```html
{{log 'my error' model}}
```

this will effectively console.log() the error that you are getting back from your route and you will get more information about what is wrong

Comment: Thank you for those code snippets, I'm going to use fetch instead

Comment: `ember-fetch` is not only about the polyfill for IE11 but also provides a better testing support. Without ember-fetch tests won't await fetch requests to be settled before entering settled state. E.g. `await click('button')` would resolve before a fetch request triggered by that click has been resolved.

Comment: very interesting @jelhan! I learn something new every day  thanks a million for the info